# How do I redirect a URL?

Tags: php, dns, forward, a-records

I would like to forward:

```
www.example.com/intake
```

to:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx/forms/intake.php
```

Do I do this by using an A record?

When I try to do this on GoDaddy I receive an error. It wants just the IP address without the specified path.

Comment: DNS just says who processes the request for domain.xyz. Everything else is done on the server. You need to configure the **web server** to redirect the request internal.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Can you please explain further, I am fairly new with this. I don't personally run the server where the subdomain is pointing to, I only control the hosting for the origin.. and right now I just have it redirecting but I would prefer for it to have the custom domain name in the address bar rather than the ip that was given to me from another company

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do this with godaddy, follow this guide: https://www.godaddy.com/help/redirect-urls-with-your-hosting-account-5120

If you want to hide the IP address, you are either going to have to set the A record of the domain to their IP and expect that server to have hosting for your domain name(not what you want), or you are going to have them listen for requests on a subdomain.

Other then that, if you are customer with godaddy, why not ask godaddy for support?

Comment: Thank you for the direction on how to handle this. and I have asked godaddy for support but I have yet to find a customer care rep that can handle this kind of question

Answer (score -1):

There's multiple ways to do what you want but using an A record has nothing to with url redirection, just dns pointers.

You can only do this if you have hosting attached to your domain name.

Comment: I don't have the ip under my hosting. it is unfortunately under another companies hosting.. What do you think would be the best way to go about it?